# Tag contains text, but also another tag with text. How do I get the text, but not the text within the extra tag with beautifulsoup python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following tag:

```
<div class="example_class">
 <b>
 <img src="image_source"/>
          extra infomation
          <a href="reference">
           extra information
          </a>
 </b>
         .
         <br/>
 <br/>
         This is the text I want to get.
         <lt>
 </lt>
         br /
         <gt>
</gt>
<lt>
</lt>
         br /
         <gt>
</gt>
<lt>
</lt>
         br /
         <gt>
</gt>
         This is the rest of the text.
</div>
```

I want to get the text 'This is the text I want to get. This is the rest of the text.', but I don't know how. When I try the following:

```py
soup_result = soup.find('div',{'class': 'example_class'})
result = soup_result.get_text()
```

I get:

```
'\n\n\n         extra information\n         \n          extra information\n         \n\n        .\n        \n\n        This is the text I want to get.\n        \n\n        br /\n        \n\n\n\n        br /\n        \n\n\n\n        br /\n        \n\n        This is the rest of the text.'
```

How do I make sure 'extra information' and the newlines with a lot of whitespaces in between are not in the result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `br /` are tags `<br />`. You can `.extract` tags you don't want in the result before `.get_text()`:

```py
div = soup.find(class_="example_class")

for b in div.find_all("b"):
    b.extract()

text = div.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n")
print(text)
```

Prints

```
.
This is the text I want to get.
This is the rest of the text.
```

Comment: What is the difference between soup.find(class_="example_class") and soup.find('div',{'class': 'example_class'})? Because the first one returns None in my case. Could this be because there is another attribute in the tag (I did not include this attribute in the example because I thought it wouldn't make a difference)

Comment: @HarmJacobs If there are more classes use the second variant. Or use CSS selector: `soup.select_one(".example_class")`

Comment: Ok, thanks, using soup.find('div',{'class': 'example_class'}) and extract() gives the right result